# Change the size/dimension of graph in ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I change the size of a plot made with ggplot2?
My actual issue is: I'm using ggplot2 R to plot data in Ipython, and I have a horizontal barplot with a lot of bar to be displayed, so I want to increase the height of the graph so I can see it better.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Change your graphics window? Change the size of the file you're writing your plot to?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check option `coord_cartesian(xlim=c(x,y), ylim=(x,y))` to rescale your graph, but if the output in `Ipython` is not in the demand size I think thisi rather `Ipython figure height/width options`-like question